# Can't select checkbox using id in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

There is the following RSpec code:

```
describe 'with valid information' do
    it 'should create a new restaurant' do
      visit new_restaurant_path

    fill_in I18n.translate(:name),          with: "Some restaurant"
      fill_in I18n.translate(:address),       with: "Some address of the restaurant"
      fill_in I18n.translate(:average_check), with: 100

    check('place_restaurant_food_types_1')

    expect { click_button :submit }.to change(Restaurant, :count).by(1)
    end
end
```

But I always get error "cannot check field, no checkbox with id, name, or label 'place_restaurant_food_types_1' found". I tried to replace id for name, but it was still the same. I'm absolutely sure that there is the item with needed id! (I copied it from the page source). How can I fix it?

HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/restaurants" class="new_place_restaurant" id="new_place_restaurant" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="7yQCirO7MLO6e+Nj46eCSNUjQWd67MJVDIHmUV6/5Y0=" /></div>
        <div class="row">
  <label for="place_restaurant_name">Название</label> 
  <input id="place_restaurant_name" name="place_restaurant[name]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="row">
  <label for="place_restaurant_address">Адрес</label> 
  <input id="place_restaurant_address" name="place_restaurant[address]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>

        <div class="row">
            <label for="place_restaurant_average_check">Средний чек</label>
            <input id="place_restaurant_average_check" name="place_restaurant[average_check]" size="30" type="text" />
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="place_restaurant_food_types_1" name="place_restaurant[food_types][1]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                <label for="place_restaurant_food_types_1">Восточная кухня</label>      
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="place_restaurant_food_types_2" name="place_restaurant[food_types][2]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                <label for="place_restaurant_food_types_2">Национальная кухня</label>       
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="place_restaurant_food_types_3" name="place_restaurant[food_types][3]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                <label for="place_restaurant_food_types_3">Японская кухня</label>       
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="place_restaurant_food_types_4" name="place_restaurant[food_types][4]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                <label for="place_restaurant_food_types_4">Китайская кухня</label>      
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="place_restaurant_food_types_5" name="place_restaurant[food_types][5]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                <label for="place_restaurant_food_types_5">Европейская кухня</label>        
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="place_restaurant_food_types_6" name="place_restaurant[food_types][6]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                <label for="place_restaurant_food_types_6">Кавказская кухня</label>     
            </div>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
<input id="latitude" name="place_restaurant[latitude]" type="hidden" value="54.352271" />
<input id="longitude" name="place_restaurant[longitude]" type="hidden" value="48.52652" />


        <div class="row">
            <input id="submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Сохранить" />
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the snippet of the Source code (html) here? That would help

Comment: How did you get that source? I'd suggest looking at what Capybara sees - immediately before your test assertion, add `puts page.html` and amend your question with that.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use

`check("place_restaurant_food_types_1")`

as shown in the [docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#check-instance_method):

> The check box can be found via name, id or label text.

Answer (score 0):

Try By Xpath like this

```
find(:xpath, "//*[@id='place_restaurant_food_types_1']").click
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
find(:css,"input[id='place_restaurant_food_types_1']").set true
```